# FutureBuilder Flutter returning no data from my calculation

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I can't get FutureBuilder to display any data from my calculation. I know the calculation is definitely correct because I can get the correct answer to be printed into the console, but just can't seem to get it to display in the app itself.

Here's the code for the code:

```
 Future<String> getBeerDrinksTarget() async {
    final user = await _auth.currentUser();
    loggedInUser = user;
    double beerNumber;
    var query = _firestore
        .collection('goals')
        .where('email', isEqualTo: '${loggedInUser.email}');

    query.getDocuments(source: Source.cache).then((data) {
      beerPercentage = data.documents[0].data['beerPercentage'];

      var y = double.parse(beerPercentage);

      double beerNumber = (y / 100) * 21;

      print('${beerNumber.toStringAsFixed(1)} target number of weekly beers');

      print('$beerPercentage% weekly beer target as a percentage of total weekly drinks');
    });

    return beerNumber.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }
```

And here's the code for the FutureBuilder widget:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
                        future: getBeerDrinksTarget(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Center(
                              child: Text(
                                '${snapshot.data}',
                              ),
                            );
                          } else
                            return Text('no data yet');
                        }),
```

The strange part about this is, if I swap `return beerNumber.toStringAsFixed(1);` to `return beerPercentage;`, it displays the beerPercentage fine in the app. This would suggest that FutureBuilder code is ok. But why does it not work when I use `return beerNumber.toStringAsFixed(1);`? That is the part I need to display in the app. It's weird because the calculation is being printed perfectly fine into the console, so that would suggest I must have made a mistake in the `FutureBuilder()` code, not the `getBeerDrinksTarget()` code.

Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Jason

Comment: if you want to use `then()` you need to `return query.getDocuments(source: Source.cache).then(...));` and return your value from the callback that is passed to `then` method - but much more easier is to use `await` as in the answer you accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final response = await query.getDocuments(source: Source.cache);
      beerPercentage = response.documents[0].data['beerPercentage'];

      var y = double.parse(beerPercentage);

      double beerNumber = (y / 100) * 21;

      print('${beerNumber.toStringAsFixed(1)} target number of weekly beers');

      print('$beerPercentage% weekly beer target as a percentage of total weekly drinks');


    return beerNumber.toStringAsFixed(1);
```

This would work. Try it and let us know so I can add an explanation.

EDITED: Added Explanation.

The reason why .then didn't work and await worked is that await suspends the execution of current function while .then continues with executing the rest of the function after adding the callback to the callback chain. As pointed by @pskink since you are returning the value outside the .then method, it is returned before .then completely executes.  And that is why, your beerPercentage was returned successfully but BEFORE the code execution reached to calculate beerNumber, a null value was already returned.
It would work fine if the return statement was also inside the then callback. Otherwise await is a much easier approach. On the other side, await stops everything else and waits for the future to resolve first and then carry on with the rest of the code.

Your print statements were also running after returning the value so you were able to see both beerNumber and beerPercentage in print.

I hope that clears the air!

Thank you for the edit @pskink

Comment: Hi @Abbas, that worked perfectly thank you so much for your help! For future reference, why did it work?

Comment: Happy to help @JasonLloyd I have added the explanation to the answer! :)

Comment: Hi @Abbas ok that makes perfect sense. Thank you again, you've been a massive help!

Comment: your explanation about `then()` could suggest that `await` has to be used instead of `then()` which is not true - you can use `then()` in that case too

Comment: Please correct me where I'm wrong so I can make a change to the answer. @pskink

Comment: if you want to use `then()` you need to `return query.getDocuments(source: Source.cache).then(...));` and return your value from the callback that is passed to `then` method

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. That is something that can be done. I'll add that to the answer in a while. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thank you @pskink for clarifying that :)